# Creating a Color Class in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create a color class in Flutter, My main objective, is that I will be able to access the colors from this class anywhere and change them when I need.

I have attempted to create like this, but I can't seem to access the variables:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorSelect {

  Color cbuttons = const Color(0xFF1520A6);
  //there will be other colors here
}
```

This is how I tried to get the color:

```
 child: Text(
                  userManager.isLoggedIn ? 'Sair' : 'Entre ou cadastre-se >',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: ColorSelect.cbuttons,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                  ),
                ),
```

but accessing the color class like this didn't work.

Comment: Why is there a constructor with `cbuttons` field when you're defining it below? Use a class with the default constructor.

Comment: @Nicks101 Just the cbuttons in class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending the answer from the comments.

I think you're confused about the concept of classes in dart (or any OOP language for that matter).

To access a property of a class, you have to instantiate it.

```dart
color: ColorSelect().cbuttons,
```

or use static properties.

```dart
class ColorSelect {

 static Color cbuttons = const Color(0xFF1520A6);
}
```

I'll encourage you to research this.

Answer (score 3):

Add `static` keyword:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorSelect {
  static final cbuttons = const Color(0xFF1520A6);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**let me suggest you better way then the Color Class**  follow the steps

Step:1 create a dart file name eg. `Colors.dar`
and in your **Colors.dart**  add the color as `const` like below
first import flutter material package.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

Step:2 define **color** which you want like below and Save the file

```
const MainBackgroundColor = const Color(0xff27a6c3);
```

Step:3 now use it you just have to import the file and use like below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 
import 'Colors.dart'; 

 /// here set the color of containe 
 
 Container(
     height: 100.0,
     width: 100.0,
     color: MainBackgroundColor,
    ),
```

you also define your all colors here in this file and use allover in your app
using this way and it is very easy to manage your theme.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    class ColorsField{
      static const buttonColor=Color(0xFF1520A6);
      static const textcolor=Color(your color);
      static const background=Color(your color);
      static const headingColor=Color(your color);
    }
Make this static so you can able to access
```